# Sublime Text 2 Compiling Error (I think)

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, sublimetext2, utf8-decode

I was using Sublime Text to compile a code I made, but it gave me this error:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

I though it was because I didn't saved it to UTF-8, but it gives me the same error.
I tried to compile it using IdeOne, it compiles fine, but it gives Time limit exceeded, but this is because of the code.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int x, d;
    for(x=1;  ; x++){
        for(d = 2; d <= 20; d++){
            if(x%d != 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(d == 21){
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

It may seem it has an infinite loop but it didn't.

Comment: Your code prints `0` and stops. No infinite loop.

Comment: I know that. But I would like to know what is wrong

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Show the number that is multiple of all numbers between 1 and 20.

Comment: Still needing help!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, `0` is an answer because `0` is a multiple of all numbers except `0`.

If you're looking for numbers from `1` onwards, you need to change your `for` loop condition from

```
for(x=0; x = x; x++){
```

to

```
for(x = 1;; x++) {
```

`x = x` will technically work because it will evaluate to true for all values except `0`. You can also start `d` from `2` instead of `1` since all numbers are divisible by `1`.

Comment: It is not my problem, I do not have problems with the code. I have problems with Sublime Text and IDEOne.

Comment: It says this: [Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.2s]